# messagefillter cannot callback. (multi subscribe /scan and /camera/depth/image_rect)

Tags: ros, message-filters, timesynchronizer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys.

I'm try to subscribe 2 topic from /scan (laser) and /camera/depth/image_rect (depth camera) for safe wandering program.
So I searched and find timesyschronizer from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#CA-073bf146ac87bef4188d36aa50bcf1c7898b34a9_9) for subscribing both topic sametime.
however, I try to implement using that sync, it seem to be cannot callback.

before runnig this node, I run first openni2 launch and rp_lidar launch to publish data.
additionally, when I subscribe each topic using simple subscriber successfully.
now I'm wandering, did I use it correct way or not.

this is piece of my source code.

```
void callback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& laser_msg, const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& depth_msg){
    printf("%20s:%5d : void callback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& laser_msg, const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& depth_msg){\n",__func__,__LINE__);
    uint8_t a[10* depth_msg->width];
    sensor_msgs::Image test_image;
    sensor_msgs::Image test_dis_image;
    
    int test_j = 0;
    
    test_image.header = depth_msg->header;
    test_image.height = 10;
    test_image.width = depth_msg->width;
    test_image.encoding = depth_msg->encoding;
    test_image.is_bigendian = depth_msg->is_bigendian;
    test_image.step = depth_msg->width;
    test_image.data.resize(test_image.width * 10);
    printf("%20s:%5d : test_image.data.resize(test_image.width * 10);\n",__func__,__LINE__);

    for ( int j =0; j < depth_msg->step; j++){
          cout << ReadDepthData(0,(int)(j/4),depth_msg) << ", " ;
    }
    
    image_publisher.publish(test_image);
    printf("%20s:%5d : image_publisher.publish(test_image);\n",__func__,__LINE__);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv){
    ros::init(argc, argv, "lidar_depth_wander");    
    ros::NodeHandle n;                      
    
    message_filters::Subscriber<LaserScan> laser_data_sub(n, "/scan", 10);
    message_filters::Subscriber<Image> image_sub(n, "/camera/depth/image_rect", 10);
    image_publisher  = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::Image>("/test_image_raw", 10);
    printf("%20s:%5d : image_publisher  = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::Image>\n",__func__,__LINE__);
    velocity_publisher = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/mobile_base/commands/velocity", 10); // for kobuki
    printf("%20s:%5d : velocity_publisher = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>; \n",__func__,__LINE__);
    
    TimeSynchronizer<LaserScan, Image> sync(laser_data_sub, image_sub, 10);
    printf("%20s:%5d : TimeSynchronizer<LaserScan, Image>\n",__func__,__LINE__);
    sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2));
    printf("%20s:%5d : sync.registerCallback\n",__func__,__LINE__);     
    
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
    ros::spin();
    printf("%20s:%5d : ros::spin();\n",__func__,__LINE__);
    
    while(ros::ok()){
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }
    printf("%20s:%5d : ending program;\n",__func__,__LINE__);
    
    return 0;
}
```

then this is CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(lidar_test_project)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS geometry_msgs message_generation roscpp rospy sensor_msgs std_msgs    message_filters)
catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS geometry_msgs message_runtime roscpp rospy sensor_msgs std_msgs message_filters
)
include_directories(
 ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
add_executable(lidar_depth_wander src/lidar_depth_wander.cpp)
target_link_libraries(lidar_depth_wander ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(lidar_depth_wander ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

last my packge.xml

```
<package>
 <name>lidar_test_project</name>
 <version>0.0.0</version>
 <description>The lidar_test_project package</description>
 <maintainer email="kang@todo.todo">kang</maintainer>
 <license>TODO</license>

 <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
 <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
 <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
 <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
 <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
 <build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend>
 <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
 <build_depend>message_filters</build_depend>
 <run_depend>geometry_msgs</run_depend>
 <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
 <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
 <run_depend>sensor_msgs</run_depend>
 <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
 <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
 <run_depend>message_filters</run_depend>
<export>
```

and program result was:

```
 main:  187 : image_publisher  = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::Image>
 main:  189 : velocity_publisher = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>; 
 main:  193 : TimeSynchronizer<LaserScan, Image>
 main:  195 : sync.registerCallback
 main:  201 : ros::spin();                                       <-- Ctrl+C
 main:  206 : ending program;
```

thanks guys.

**ADD**
I tried to subscribe /camera/depth/image_rect and camera/depth/image_rect_raw as same topic and same message type. It was working well. so I thinking now it is sync problem maybe. so now I want to know i need to make these to be synchronized also or make queue for getting data..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223207/messagefillter-cannot-callback.-(multi-subscribe-/scan-and-/camera/depth/image_rect)/) by [haryngod](https://answers.ros.org/users/25155/haryngod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2015-12-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's rather rare for two publishers to be *exactly* synchronised in time, so for normal cases I'd expect the [ApproximateTime](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#ApproximateTime_Policy) Policy to be a better choice.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [haryngod](https://answers.ros.org/users/25155/haryngod/) on 2015-12-29**:
Oh! thanks to you!!! it is working well to me.:)